# Mantel test unequal samples between dissimilarity matrices

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, biostatistics

I googled but did not find any answer for my problem.

So, I have two multivariate datasets, concernit two different communities (in fact more, but here lets stick to two):

1. abundance of macrofauna taxa, like:

[image: macrofauna dataset]

2. abundance of bacteria taxa, like

[image: bacteria dataset]

Samples were collected at the same stations. But for *macrofauna* there were 4 samples collected at each station, while for *bacteria* there were 3 samples collected eatch each station.
Samples does not correspond between datasets i.e. *macrofauna*;station1;*sampleA* **does not refer to** *bacteria*;station1;*sampleA*.
There is no common taxa between this two datasets.

For each dataset I did ordination analysis - nMDS (based on Bray-Curtis dissimilarity) to assess simmilarieties in species composition among samples (stations).

[image: two nMDS]

Now I would like to compare this datasets - test if this two ordinations are similar (correlated). I though about mantel test, but the probles is unequal sample size.

What would be the most suitable way to do this?

- Pool all data from each station together, average each taxon abundance and make dissimilarity matrices based on station (not sample) data?
- Make disssimilarity
  matrices based on samples and calculate mean dissimilarities among stations and then do Mantel test?

I work in R

Comment: This is hard to understand. You don't say what measurements are in the multivariate data. You don't say what you mean by "group" or what is actually sampled. You mention "species abundance" at some point but neither species nor abundance has been mentioned before, so we don't know how species abundance relates to your data. Neither do I understand what exactly you mean by "they discriminate stations the same way".  Can you formalise your null hypothesis, explain clearly how your data set looks like, and explain how all used terminology is related to your data?

Comment: Dear @ChristianHennig I added examples and tried to better explain everthing. I hope it is more understandable now

Comment: OK, this makes your thinking much clearer, and how you arrived at your two options. Both of these make some sense. I'd roughly tend to the first one, as ultimately you work at station level, and I think it is "cleaner" to keep the stations separated before the final test, but I'm not sure. I don't really understand the sampling process and how the samples are informative for what goes on at a station. If the given numbers are real, some strange things seem to go on there, and maybe something is required that takes this better into account. What to do may depend on more knowledge about this.